# Change user's roles displaying type configuration EasyAdminBundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I have to display user's roles as a list: Instead of typing it, I would like to click on the choices. I'll get choices like ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN,...

Is there any configuration changes than I have to make in my config.yml?

Thanks for your help,
Anis

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You must use [choice type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) and its `expanded` option (and optionally, the `multiple` option too). Remember that options meant for the form types are defined in the `type_options` option:

```
easy_admin:
    # ...
    entities:
        User:
            # ...
            form:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'roles', type: 'choice', type_options: { expanded: true } }
```

You can also define the options in the YAML file if you want:

```
easy_admin:
    # ...
    entities:
        User:
            # ...
            form:
                fields:
                    - property: 'roles'
                      type: 'choice'
                      type_options:
                        expanded: true
                        choices: { 'ROLE_USER': 'Normal user', 'ROLE_ADMIN': 'Administrator' }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I tried them both and when I click on add new User I got and error saying: "The value of type "array" cannot be converted to a valid array key." Do you have any idea about the solution?

Comment: @AnisAbida Try adding `multiple: true` to the type_options as well. And you'll want to reverse the keys and values (i.e. swap ROLE_USER and Normal user, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Took a while, but here's a possible method to add a checkbox to add or remove the role `ROLE_ADMIN` to a user:

in your easyadmin config, for the User entity, add:
`- {property: 'hasRoleAdmin', label: 'Is admin', type: checkbox}`

Or, for a drop down that does the same thing:

```
- {property: 'hasRoleAdmin', label: 'Role', type: choice, type_options: choices: {0: 'ROLE_USER', 1: 'ROLE_ADMIN'}}}
```

In your User entity, add:

```
public function hasRoleAdmin()
{
    return $this->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
}

public function setHasRoleAdmin($isAdmin)
{
    if (true == $isAdmin && false == $this->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $this->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');

    }
    if (false == $isAdmin && true == $this->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $this->removeRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }
    $this->isAdmin = $isAdmin;
}
```